# D3: Force layout + blocking work

Tags: javascript, d3.js, force-layout

How would one do a blocking work on other thread (e.g. loading data) while using a force layout?

With the simplest possible example of force layout (http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045), I tried two things:

```
setInterval(function() {
  console.debug('BEGIN');
  for (var i = 0; i < 1000000000; ++ i);
  console.debug('END');
}, 2000);
```

and:

```
var run = function() {
  console.debug('BEGIN');
  for (var i = 0; i < 1000000000; ++ i);
  console.debug('END');

  d3.timer(run, 500);

  return true;
};

d3.timer(run, 500);
```

But unfortunately, both seem to do the same. Block force layout's tick. This can be seen here: http://bl.ocks.org/mfolnovic/8193673.

I've read http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/, and I think I understand why this happens. Is there a different way to work around this issue?

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do here. Why are you trying to block? There's usually no need to "pause" a force layout when the data is being updated.

Comment: If you want to pause and resume the force ticks so the CPU can focus on your data load, there are [easy functions for that](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout#wiki-resume); if you're trying to load the data in the background *without* interfering with the force layout, then you're going to need to create a well-behaved [asynchronous background thread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Performance/Using_web_workers) to do that work.  The [D3 data loading functions](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Requests) work this way.